# What is wrong with my \begin{definition}?

Tags: pdftex, undefined

I am completely new in LaTeX. I wrote this below code in TeXworks but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
In this section I introduce some concepts which we need to fully understand the Ellipsoid method.
\begin{definition}
A set $S\in \mathbb R^n$ is said affine set if for every $x,y \in S$ and every $\lambda in \mathbb R$ we have $\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y\in S$.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Could you please help me what is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very simple: there is no `definition` theorem-like environment by default. There's  only a ‘definition’ `theorem style`. So here is how to define it, numbered by section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this section I introduce some concepts which we need to fully understand the Ellipsoid method.
\begin{definition}
A set $S\in \mathbb R^n$ is said affine set if for every $x,y \in S$ and every $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ we have $\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y\in S$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask what is usage of \theoremstyle{definition}? and also what about the [section] because with out [section] still it works.

Comment: Every theorem declaration that follows will have this style (heading in upshape boldface, body in upshape). The default is `plain` style (similar header, body in italic). You can define an own style, and the `thmtools` package is particularly useful for this job.